# Sending a JSON created in Play framework over a websocket

Tags: json, coffeescript, websocket, playframework-2.0

That is what I get in *browser* console:

```
WS-PARSER: received {"eventPhase":2,"origin":"","bubbles":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"srcElement":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","url":"ws://localhost:9000/map-socket/a@a.com","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":1,"onerror":null,"onopen":null,"onclose":null,"protocol":"","URL":"ws://localhost:9000/map-socket/a@a.com"},"type":"message","returnValue":true,"target":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","url":"ws://localhost:9000/map-socket/a@a.com","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":1,"onerror":null,"onopen":null,"onclose":null,"protocol":"","URL":"ws://localhost:9000/map-socket/a@a.com"},"source":null,"cancelable":false,"currentTarget":{"binaryType":"blob","extensions":"","url":"ws://localhost:9000/map-socket/a@a.com","bufferedAmount":0,"readyState":1,"onerror":null,"onopen":null,"onclose":null,"protocol":"","URL":"ws://localhost:9000/map-socket/a@a.com"},"ports":[],"timeStamp":1341430631884,"lastEventId":"","cancelBubble":false,"data":"{\"stars\":[{\"x\":\"0.0\",\"y\":\"0.0\",\"own\":\"-1\",\"id\":\"0\",\"units\":\"0\"},{\"x\":\"0.0\",\"y\":\"0.0\",\"own\":\"-1\",\"id\":\"1\",\"units\":\"0\"},{\"x\":\"0.0\",\"y\":\"0.0\",\"own\":\"0\",\"id\":\"2\",\"units\":\"0\"}]}"}
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Why does the first part of the message (automatic) has that many header repetitions? Is this ok, should I leave it like that or can I somehow reduce the amount of the boilerplate?

2) Why are all the quotes in the second part of the message (my payload) escaped?

Here is the code that formulates the JSON:

```
val stars = strs.getAll.map(_.asJsValue).toSeq
Json.toJson(
    Map(
        "stars" -> stars
        )
)
```

the `asJsValue` method:

```
  def asJsValue = {
    Json.toJson(
        Map(
            "id" -> id.toString,
            "x" -> x.toString,
            "y" -> y.toString,
            "units" -> units.toString,
            "own" -> getOwnerID.toString
        )
    )
  }
```

and on the client side:

```
websocket.onmessage = receivedEvent

receiveEvent = (event) ->
  console.log("WS-PARSER: received " + JSON.stringify(event))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most of that data is added on the client-side, only the `data` value is sent over the wire
2. JSON requires double quotes, that's why they are escaped

*(disclaimer: not a play user)*

Comment: So the double quotes are escaped because they themselves are inside the string called `data` and the escape slashes are there because the string is outputed to the screen and really they are not there?

 I mean if I work with that `data` string as JSON, then everything will be fine or shall I get into trouble?

Comment: How would you represent nested quotes without the slashes, or other escape char? :) They are added by the `stringify` call. If you print/log/use that string you'll see that they "disappear". `JSON.parse(message.data)` should work fine.